# ADX Support with MVC 5 and CRM 2013

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, crm, dynamics-crm-2013, adxstudio-portals

We have an idea to use ADX with MVC 5 and CRM 2013.

Is it possible?

We are doing background research on this whether to use ADX or not.
We have used ASP.NET with ADX previously.
This will help take a decision and will save our time.
Appreciate help if anyone know about this.

Adx portal - http://www.adxstudio.com/products/adxstudio-portals/

Comment: The question is to vague. Did you try anything? Did something go wrong while trying?

Comment: We are doing background research on this whether to use ADX or not.we have used ASP.NET with ADX previously.This will help take a decision  and will save our time. Appreciate help if anyone know about this.

Comment: Is it possible ? Of course. Is it convenient ? I doubt it. OData endpoints and not-that-bad SDK make it easy to tailor your code to your needs. We used adx back in CRM4 but we don't feel the need for it any longer now in 2011/13

Answer (score 2):

ADX offers a great product with an impressive feature list.  http://www.adxstudio.com/products/adxstudio-portals/portals-features/

Like any add-on, look to see if there is something it contains that you deem as being vital and valuable enough to justify.  Additionally, does your team have the ability/time to create the end product with or without ADX?

This is an opinion based question and in my opinion, none of the features alone justify the price.  Especially seeing that ASP.NET + NuGet pretty much covers most of these features already.

Answer (score 0):

Adxstudio Portals delivers managed forms by rendering a form in an Adxstudio Portal based on a particular form or view customization defined on an entity in CRM. Within CRM, entities can be customized and forms and views can be modified or created depending on your requirements.

https://community.adxstudio.com/products/adxstudio-portals/users-guide/managed-forms/

and

https://community.adxstudio.com/products/adxstudio-portals/developers-guide/web-controls/crmentityformview/

Above is the main reason us to consider ADX Studio.

Answer (score 0):

ADX Studio, offers a good tool set to the client that has an internal developing team that will pick it up after you finish to customize it. Basically you provide some page template and the user is able to mess around with the forms to have a tailored experience (this works well when you don't have any logic on the page, just set the page and you are ready to go). Anything that is not in this category is custom made, means that you need to code it, and you will lose all the additional ADX benefits (for what concerns the read/write to CRM). Consider that a CRM developer is not a full asp/mvc developer, so anything that is more complex than change some code behind in a page template will create you problems, also all the jscript on the adx pages needs to be tailored, and you will need developers that are knowing the current web development standards, from Bootstrap to a decent js framework. Personally I'm not a huge fan, but the built-in authentication and some other features are making it a viable product. Consider that to customize it you will need someone that knows responsive design and js.